# Disable Mod Pagespeed for specific URL via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-pagespeed

I am trying to disable mod_pagespeed from running at all on a specific URL by adding a condition to .htaccess. I only have access to .htaccess.

When I add this:

```
<Location "/web/*">
    ModPagespeed off
</Location>
```

I get a server error.

I am needing any URL that starts with /web/ to have ModPagespeed disabled.
So `/web/page1/` `/web/page2/` as well.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. It's very simply:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed on
    ModPagespeedDisallow "*/web/*"
</IfModule>
```